# Не работает ajax-функция для валидации

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, валидация

Есть страница регистрации, выглядит следующим образом:

```
<?php
include("include/db_connect.php");
include("functions/functions.php");
?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html lang="ru">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="trackbar/trackbar.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/reset.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
    <!--<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script> -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jcarousellite_1.0.1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/shop-script.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/reg-val.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery.cookie.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/trackbar/jquery.trackbar.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery.form.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery.validate.js"></script>
    <title>Регистрация</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="block-body">
        <!-- Подключение шапки сайта -->
        <?php
            include("include/block-header.php"); 
         ?>
         <!-- Подключение блоков категорий товаров, фильтра параметров и новостей -->
        <div id="block-right">
            <?php
                include("include/block-category.php");   
                include("include/block-parameter.php");
                include("include/block-news.php");
             ?>
        </div>
        <!-- Блок отображения основного контента сайта -->
        <div id="block-content">
            <h2 class="h2-title">Регистрация</h2>
            <form action="/reg/handler_reg.php" method="POST" id="form_reg">
                <p id="reg_message"></p>
                <div id="block-form-registration">
                    <ul id="form-registration">
                        <li>
                            <label for="">Логин</label>
                            <span class="star">*</span>
                            <input type="text" name="reg_login" id="reg_login">
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <label for="">Пароль</label>
                            <span class="star">*</span>
                            <input type="text" name="reg_pass" id="reg_pass">
                            <span id="genpass">Сгенерировать</span>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <label for="">Фамилия</label>
                            <span class="star">*</span>
                            <input type="text" name="reg_surname" id="reg_surname">
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <label for="">Имя</label>
                            <span class="star">*</span>
                            <input type="text" name="reg_name" id="reg_name">
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <label for="">Отчество</label>
                            <span class="star">*</span>
                            <input type="text" name="reg_patronymic" id="reg_patronymic">
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <label for="">E-mail</label>
                            <span class="star">*</span>
                            <input type="text" name="reg_email" id="reg_email">
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <label for="">Мобильный телефон</label>
                            <span class="star">*</span>
                            <input type="text" name="reg_phone" id="reg_phone">
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <label for="">Адрес доставки</label>
                            <span class="star">*</span>
                            <input type="text" name="reg_address" id="reg_address">
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <div id="block-captcha">
                                <img src="/reg/reg_captcha.php" alt="captcha">
                                <input type="text" name="reg_captcha" id="reg_captcha">
                                <p id="reloadcaptcha">Обновить</p>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <p align="right">
                    <input type="submit" name="reg_submit" id="form_submit" value="Регистрация">
                </p>
            </form>
        </div>
        <!-- Подключение нижней части сайта -->
        <?php
            include("include/block-footer.php"); 
         ?>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Есть так же обработчик, который вносит данные с формы регистрации в базу:

```
<?php
 if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST")
{ 
 session_start();
 define('myeshop', true);
 include("../include/db_connect.php");
 include("../functions/functions.php");

     $error = array();

        $login = iconv("UTF-8", "cp1251",strtolower(clearString($_POST['reg_login']))); 
        $pass = iconv("UTF-8", "cp1251",strtolower(clearString($_POST['reg_pass']))); 
        $surname = iconv("UTF-8", "cp1251",clearString($_POST['reg_surname'])); 

        $name = iconv("UTF-8", "cp1251",clearString($_POST['reg_name'])); 
        $patronymic = iconv("UTF-8", "cp1251",clearString($_POST['reg_patronymic'])); 
        $email = iconv("UTF-8", "cp1251",clearString($_POST['reg_email'])); 

        $phone = iconv("UTF-8", "cp1251",clearString($_POST['reg_phone'])); 
        $address = iconv("UTF-8", "cp1251",clearString($_POST['reg_address'])); 


    if (strlen($login) < 5 or strlen($login) > 15)
    {
       $error[] = "Логин должен быть от 5 до 15 символов!"; 
    }
    else
    {   
     $result = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT login FROM reg_user WHERE login = '$login'");
    If (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)
    {
       $error[] = "Логин занят!";
    }

    }

    if (strlen($pass) < 7 or strlen($pass) > 15) $error[] = "Укажите пароль от 7 до 15 символов!";
    if (strlen($surname) < 3 or strlen($surname) > 20) $error[] = "Укажите Фамилию от 3 до 20 символов!";
    if (strlen($name) < 3 or strlen($name) > 15) $error[] = "Укажите Имя от 3 до 15 символов!";
    if (strlen($patronymic) < 3 or strlen($patronymic) > 25) $error[] = "Укажите Отчество от 3 до 25 символов!";
    if (!preg_match("/^(?:[a-z0-9]+(?:[-_.]?[a-z0-9]+)?@[a-z0-9_.-]+(?:\.?[a-z0-9]+)?\.[a-z]{2,5})$/i",trim($email))) $error[] = "Укажите корректный email!";
    if (!$phone) $error[] = "Укажите номер телефона!";
    if (!$address) $error[] = "Необходимо указать адрес доставки!";

    if($_SESSION['img_captcha'] != strtolower($_POST['reg_captcha'])) $error[] = "Неверный код с картинки!";
    unset($_SESSION['img_captcha']);

   if (count($error))
   {

 echo implode('<br />',$error);

   }else
   {   
        $pass   = md5($pass);
        $pass   = strrev($pass);
        $pass   = "9nm2rv8q".$pass."2yo6z";

        $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

        mysqli_query($link, "INSERT INTO reg_user(login,password,surname,name,patronymic,email,phone,address,datetime,ip)
                        VALUES(
                            '".$login."',
                            '".$pass."',
                            '".$surname."',
                            '".$name."',
                            '".$patronymic."',
                            '".$email."',
                            '".$phone."',
                            '".$address."',
                            NOW(),
                            '".$ip."'                           
                        )");

 echo true;
 }        
}
?>
```

И есть скрипт, в котором происходит валидация данных, а так же вывод ajax'ом уведомления о том, что регистрация успешно прошла.

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
            $('#form_reg').validate(
                        {   
                            // правила для проверки
                            rules:{
                                "reg_login":{
                                    required:true,
                                    minlength:5,
                                    maxlength:15,
                                    remote: {
                                    type: "post",    
                                    url: "/reg/check_login.php"
                                            }
                                },
                                "reg_pass":{
                                    required:true,
                                    minlength:7,
                                    maxlength:15
                                },
                                "reg_surname":{
                                    required:true,
                                    minlength:3,
                                    maxlength:15
                                },
                                "reg_name":{
                                    required:true,
                                    minlength:3,
                                    maxlength:15
                                },
                                "reg_patronymic":{
                                    required:true,
                                    minlength:3,
                                    maxlength:25
                                },
                                "reg_email":{
                                    required:true,
                                    email:true
                                },
                                "reg_phone":{
                                    required:true
                                },
                                "reg_address":{
                                    required:true
                                },
                                "reg_captcha":{
                                    required:true,
                                    remote: {
                                    type: "post",    
                                    url: "/reg/check_captcha.php"

                                    }
                                }
                            },

                            // выводимые сообщения при нарушении соответствующих правил
                            messages:{
                                "reg_login":{
                                    required:"Укажите Логин!",
                                    minlength:"От 5 до 15 символов!",
                                    maxlength:"От 5 до 15 символов!",
                                    remote: "Логин занят!"
                                },
                                "reg_pass":{
                                    required:"Укажите Пароль!",
                                    minlength:"От 7 до 15 символов!",
                                    maxlength:"От 7 до 15 символов!"
                                },
                                "reg_surname":{
                                    required:"Укажите вашу Фамилию!",
                                    minlength:"От 3 до 20 символов!",
                                    maxlength:"От 3 до 20 символов!"                            
                                },
                                "reg_name":{
                                    required:"Укажите ваше Имя!",
                                    minlength:"От 3 до 15 символов!",
                                    maxlength:"От 3 до 15 символов!"                               
                                },
                                "reg_patronymic":{
                                    required:"Укажите ваше Отчество!",
                                    minlength:"От 3 до 25 символов!",
                                    maxlength:"От 3 до 25 символов!"  
                                },
                                "reg_email":{
                                    required:"Укажите свой E-mail",
                                    email:"Не корректный E-mail"
                                },
                                "reg_phone":{
                                    required:"Укажите номер телефона!"
                                },
                                "reg_address":{
                                    required:"Необходимо указать адрес доставки!"
                                },
                                "reg_captcha":{
                                    required:"Введите код с картинки!",
                                    remote: "Не верный код проверки!"
                                }
                            },

            submitHandler: function(form){
            $(form).ajaxSubmit({
            success: function(data) { 
                        if (data == true) {
                            $("#block-form-registration").fadeOut(300,function() {

                                $("#reg_message").addClass("reg_message_good").fadeIn(400).html("Вы успешно зарегистрированы!");
                                $("#form_submit").hide();
                            });
                        } else {
                            $("#reg_message").addClass("reg_message_error").fadeIn(400).html(data); 
                        }
                    } 
                }); 
            }
        });
    });
```

Так вот, скрипт подключен (в первом листинге это видно, файл reg-val.js), валидация работает прекрасно, но при нажатии "регистрация" сообщения аджаксом не выводится, лишь переходит на файл второго листинга (handler_reg.php) и выводит на пустую страницу цифру 1...При этом данные с формы успешно заносятся в БД!!! В чем может быть проблема? Целый день не могу отловить ошибку...

Comment: В консоли смотрели ошибки? Посылается запрос?

Comment: @E_p почему вы так считаете?

Comment: Посмотрел библиотеку, похоже просто api такой, игнорируйте мой коментарий.

Comment: @AlexandrKiseloy в консоли пусто. Если функцию с аджаксом закомментировать,то всё тоже самое...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Удивительным образом, но всё заработало путём использования Jquery версии 1.8.2... На нескольких иных версиях, в том числе и гугловой и 2.2.4, которую я использовал ранее, почему-то не работает...

Answer (score 0):

Проблема может быть в том что функция которая вызывается по нажатию кнопки не возвращает false и в свою очередь срабатывает стандартный submit html формы.

submitHandler: function(form){
...
return false;
}

Comment: можно подробнее, пожалуйста?

Comment: увы, но всё как и прежде...

Comment: Тогда советую использовать консоль браузера или расширение для браузера которое показывает http заголовки. Таким образом вы сможете определить в какой момент происходит редирект.